# SEO How To Handle Pages That Require Login & Payment?

Tags: seo, ranking, authentication, payments, cloaking

If you have URLs on your site that require a login but a user who is not logged in tries to access those login required URLs, how do you handle it? 401, 403, 404, 301 to a login page?

If the page requires login but also requires payment, how do you handle that?

Have an error message on the current page you are on say that you must be logged in to view this page?

What would rank better for search engine bots?

I want to avoid cloaking and any negative things that would cause lower rankings. It would be nice to be able to rank for those pages that are behind the login though since that is where a lot of my main content will be.

Comment: related: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2017/10/enabling-more-high-quality-content.html

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister what if the free content is behind a login though? Can Google still see it? I was planning on having free content behind a login but how do you let Google see it? When it says structured data does it mean use schema.org?

Comment: No, you'll have to give the Google crawler bot special login-less access if you want it to crawl those pages. You'll want to use the noarchive tag too, to make sure people can't just pluck your paid content out of the Google cache. I would elaborate but I'm busy tonight! Just wanted to share that link

Comment: How do I give Google crawler bot special login access? I will look into the noarchive tag that is good advice, thanks for that and the link.

Comment: Here's how to identify googlebot. The basic idea is to use server side code to identify it and let it through. You have to be very careful not to violate any guidelines like cloaking, but that's near the limits of my knowledge. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/80553?hl=en

Comment: I see so how would I give googlebot the username and password they need to be able to look at my login only pages?

Comment: The idea is to verify googlebot, then get your server to show it premium content without any login. This is what many news sites do. But like I said, there's some particular way you need to do it to be above board with Google guidelines and not be considered cloaking, that I'm not familiar with. It's a lot of work just to get premium content indexed.

Comment: Wow it seems so complicated. I am using Django and maybe I can use https://blog.majsky.cz/detecting-google-bot-python-and-django/ or https://github.com/macropin/django-googlebot. Will these work?

Comment: Looks good in theory. Like I said this is not my area of expertise. I would be careful not to violate Google cloaking guidelines. I just know about the general concept of this, haven't implemented it before. I wish you luck!

Comment: Thanks. So if I were to do nothing about this and just use something like a 401, 403, 404, 301, would that still hurt me? Would I still be violating cloaking?